# What is the best way to expand existing data in a database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

So I've got a field in my database that will contain serial id numbers separated by commas eg. 2817,2385,4937,3298 I want to be able to add more numbers to the same field over time.

The best way I can think to do this is to get the contents, add the new numbers to it, and insert them back into the database.

What I'm wondering is if there's a more direct way. I had trouble thinking of a good way to word this that yields helpful search results so I'm asking here.

Comment: There is a more direct way: Use normalization with n:n or n:m relations.

Comment: Don't design your database with comma separated data in a column; NORMALIZE, NORMALIZE, NORMALIZE

Comment: @Mittens - don't use a *relational* database as if it's a file on your hard drive. It's called **relational** because you establish relations between tables. You insert ROWS with numbers, you don't update a single row with comma separated values. The database then allows you to use those rows while querying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is.

```
UPDATE `table` SET `column` = CONCAT(`column`,',new_serial')
```

However this is not right, you should never store comma separated values. It's called database normalization.

Comment: Thanks! I know you're not supposed to do it this way, just saw that someone else did and thought I'd give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE `tableName` SET `yourColum` = CONCAT(`yourColumn`, ',nextId')
```

This will update your column as you requested.

Comment: Delete your post to save confusion. I just deleted mine as I did the same thing.